# probability of difference of random variable less than a constant K

Tags: probability

Let me assume two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are exponentially distributed.

$$
X \sim \exp(\lambda_x) \\
Y \sim \exp(\lambda_y)
$$

Let me also assume a constant $K$ between $-2$ and $2$

How should I go about calculating the probability
$$p(X-Y < K)$$

a. assuming independence of $X$ and $Y $: 
I think this can be written as
$$ \frac{\exp(-\lambda_y K) \lambda_x}{\lambda_x + \lambda_y}$$

would this be right?

b. assuming correlation between $X$ and $Y$ (non-independence)

I need help in this scenario.

Comment: You can condition on all possible values of X. Or, draw the region of interest in the x-y plane and double-integrate over that region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we recognize that as $Y > 0$ them $X < K$ implies $X - Y < K$. So we can calculate the probability 
$$P(X - Y < K) = P(X \leq K) + P(X > K, Y \geq X - K)$$
for which finding the first term can be done using the definition of the cdf, wheres the second term can be found by conditioning over all values of $x$
$$
P(X - Y < K) = F_X(K) + \int_K^{\infty} f_X(x')(1 - F_Y(x'-K)) dx'.
$$ 
Inserting for $f_X, F_X$ and $F_Y$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
P(X - Y < K) &= 1 - \exp(-\lambda_x K) + \int_K^{\infty} \lambda_x \exp(-\lambda_x x')(1-1+\exp(-\lambda_y x')) dx' = \\
P(X - Y < K) &= 1 - \exp(-\lambda_x K) + \int_K^{\infty} \lambda_x \exp(-(\lambda_x + \lambda_y) x')) dx' = \\
P(X - Y < K) &= 1 - \exp(-\lambda_x K) -  \frac{\lambda_x}{\lambda_x + \lambda_y}\bigg[\exp(-(\lambda_x + \lambda_y) x')\bigg]_K^{\infty} = \\
P(X - Y < K) &= 1 - \exp(-\lambda_x K) +  \frac{\lambda_x}{\lambda_x + \lambda_y}\exp(-(\lambda_x + \lambda_y) K)
\end{align} = \\
$$

PS: I'm doing this pretty late so please let me know if I did something incorrect.

Comment: That is a neat approach. I did not foresee the $p(X>K, Y >= X-K)$. Thanks Michael.